# solc 0.7.0 --allow-paths --base-path woes on (Version: 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Linux.g++)

Tags: solidity, library

I have a library Foo.sol in `/logicalroot/src/main/sol/lib/Foo.sol`

I have a contract MyContract in `/logicalroot/src/main/sol/contracts/MyContract.sol`
That contract sources this:

```
import {Foo} from "Foo.sol";
```

Executing from `/logicalroot`

```
solc-static-linux-0.7.0 --abi --bin --overwrite -o build/main src/main/sol/contracts/MyContract.sol
```

I cannot get solc to find the `import` despite many permutations of command line args and import decs, e.g.:

```
import {Foo} from "Foo.sol";
import {Foo} from "./Foo.sol";
import {Foo} from "/Foo.sol";
import {Foo} from "../lib/Foo.sol";
```

and all manner of `--allow-paths` and `--base-path` setups.  The only way I can get it to run is with `Foo.sol` copied into the same dir as `MyControl.sol` and no command line `--allow-paths` or `--base-path` args and the import being:

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo.sol";  // NOTICE the dot slash path!
```

Then it works perfectly fine!  But **not even a symlink** works, e.g.

```
$ cd contracts
$ ln -s ../lib/Foo.sol .
```

Is this a `solc 0.7.0` issue perhaps?  Any clues for an old-time C `#include "file.h"` guy would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem, the only workaround I have found is to pass the `..=..` argument to solc, so it will correctly interpret the paths.

So my layout is:

```
├── artifacts
├── contr
│   └── A.sol
└── somedir
    └── B.sol
```

contracts/A.sol:

```
...
import "../somedir/B.sol";
...
```

And I run solc from the root dir in the following way:

```
solc --abi --bin contr/A.sol -o artifacts --overwrite ..=..
```

Comment: Yikes -- but yes that works.